# jQuery Cycle2 Not Working At All

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2, cycle2

I have used Cycle2 many times before with no problems, but for some reason I cannot get it to work at all. I have included the latest jQuery CDN, Cycle2, Cycle2 Shuffle and jQuery Easing.

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-timeout="5000" data-cycle-fx="shuffle" data-cycle-shuffle-top="-125" data-cycle-shuffle-left="0" data-cycle-speed="1100" data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true" data-cycle-slides="> div.homepage-carousel-item" data-cycle-swipe="true"
  data-cycle-ease-out="easeOutBack" data-cycle-easing="easeInOutBack">
  <div class="homepage-carousel-item"><img alt="" src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-v0soe-ievYE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/OixOH_h84Po/s900-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"></div>
  <div class="homepage-carousel-item"><img alt="" src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-v0soe-ievYE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/OixOH_h84Po/s900-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"></div>
  <div class="homepage-carousel-item"><img alt="" src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-v0soe-ievYE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/OixOH_h84Po/s900-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

I have a [jsfiddle set up here](https://jsfiddle.net/xxw8nmgj/6/). Am I missing something super obvious???

Comment: Have you looked at the console errors in your fiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this...

```css
img {
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
}
.homepage-carousel-item{
  background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle2/2.1.6/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle2/2.1.6/plugin/jquery.cycle2.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle2/2.1.6/plugin/jquery.cycle2.swipe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle2/2.1.6/plugin/jquery.cycle2.shuffle.min.js"></script>

<div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-timeout="5000" data-cycle-fx="shuffle" data-cycle-shuffle-top="-125" data-cycle-shuffle-left="0" data-cycle-speed="1100" data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true" data-cycle-slides="> div.homepage-carousel-item" data-cycle-swipe="true"
data-cycle-ease-out="easeOutBack" data-cycle-easing="easeInOutBack">
  <div class="homepage-carousel-item"><img alt="" src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-v0soe-ievYE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/OixOH_h84Po/s900-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"></div>
  <div class="homepage-carousel-item"><img alt="" src="https://www.google.com/gmail/about/images/any-device.jpg"></div>
  <div class="homepage-carousel-item"><img alt="" src="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"></div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/geogeorge/o2s54ctw/

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize I needed to include the cycle2.carousel as well as the cycle2.min.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong URL try this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
```